# why apply "to_date" ,in a "where" expression, on a variable that is already of type "date"?

Tags: mysql

I have a feeling that this question should be easy to answer, yet for some reason, i searched everywhere and came empty handed, even using the search function in mysql docs didn't return a "to_date" function at all!!! 
can someone explain why the use of "to_date" on "bdate" that is already a "date" variable?why converting it to date again ? actually an explanation of "to_date" is appreciated, since searching the docs didn't produce anything useful?
in some lecture slides the professor gave an example:

```
mysql> create table student
(SID DECIMAL(7) primary key not null,
SNAME VARCHAR (20), MAJOR CHAR(4), YEAR DEC(1),
BDATE DATE);
```

then he query it using:

```
select s.sname
from student s
where to_date(s.bdate) like '%13%';
```

Comment: There is no `to_date()` function in MySQL.  What database are you really using?

Comment: exactly! in the "create table" he is clearly using MYSQL, but my research returned exactly what you said!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this question is really about Oracle or Postgres which have a `to_date()` function, this seems like a very bad idea.  Perhaps the intention is more like:

```
select s.sname
from student s
where to_char(s.bdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') like '%13%';
```

In addition to using `to_date()` the `like` comparison is assuming strings.  Conversion to a date does not make sense (to me) in this case.

EDIT:

I should add that [Oracle explicitly warns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) against doing this:

> Do not use the TO_DATE function with a DATE value for the char
>   argument. The first two digits of the returned DATE value can differ
>   from the original char, depending on fmt or the default date format.

Comment: is the function "to_date" available in MYSQL?

Comment: @Molegrammer . . . Unless the "professor" is explaining everything wrong with the statement (these come to mind:  using Oracle/Postgres function in MySQL, using `like` to compare dates, passing an invalid argument in, not using the format), then I would question the competence of the instructor.

Comment: yeah,so far looks like a completely wrong example, unless he is using some old version of MYSQL, he is an ancient professor after all!